# Is this approach to loading dynamic data via memcached possible? feasible?

Tags: php, sql, memcached

Ok, so I haven't gotten into the nitty gritty of working with memcached just yet, as I'm brainstorming/planning how I might go about a memcached solution before I just start hacking away and make something awful.

Here's the environment: The website displays a list of deals from a lot of different vendors, sorted by popularity of the deal (think of a big grid). Non users always see the same grid, but users can choose favorite vendors so that deals from their favorite vendors always appear first.

How it's working now: If a non-user opens the site, a SQL query is sent to get all the deal info from table `deals`, which is then used to populate the html necessary for the page. If a user enters the site, a little more advanced SQL query, basically a left join of `deals` and `userfavorites`, is sent that orders the deals as described above and populates the html.

What I want to do: Obviously, the non-user SQL query seems perfect for memcached, as it's always the same until the `deals` table is updated (which can just update the memcached version at the same time, I'm guessing). However, since users are going to have a bunch of variation for their favorites, I'm wondering how I might go about a caching solution for them as well. All of the data the user sees is exactly the same as the non-user, the only difference is the order. It seems nonsensical to me to perform queries for data that will already be available in the cache. Would it be possible to cache `deals` and `userfavorites (where userid=?)`, then perform left-join & order actions on them artificially using PHP?

Basically, something like this?

```
memcached version of deals (desc order by pageviews)
memcached version of favorites (specific to the user)

favoritecount = 0
for i = 0, i < length(deals), i++
    if deals.i.vendor is a member of favorites
        push deals.i to deals.favoritecount
        favoritecount++
    else
        continue
```

If I'm thinking about this correctly, because `deals` is already sorted and it's being processed sequentially, this should produce a deals list in the form of `favorites (desc order by pageviews)` ∪ `deals (desc order by pageviews)`, which I can use to spit out the html.

Of course, I could have checks in place such that if a user adds or removes a favorite, it updates their cached version.

What do you guys think? Is this possible? I want my users touching my database as little as possible for data that is mostly the same, so I'm hoping memcached will allow me to do what I've described above. As it stands at the moment, every single hit to the website is touching the database. Thanks for taking the time to read through this, any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small enough set of deals, you can definitely cache them as data rather than as HTML, meaning that NO ONE has to hit your database. Then you can have a second cache for the "guest" version in its finished HTML format. Then for members, do the sorting in code and build the HTML each time.

If you're REALLY concerned about load, and you're sending the complete list of data to your users anyway, do the sorting client-side. Cache a json string with all the data, and then for members pass along a second json string containing weights for their preferred vendors, and then mix/sort client-side. There are plenty of jquery libs for sorting tables and such, and the weights could be included as hidden metadata on the columns.

If your data set is large enough that you are not sending it all at once, and are instead paging things, then I'm afraid none of this will work. If the system can't handle the load of building the pages dynamically for members, then you may have to re-think your design.